# Adding variable amount of lines to file in Bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with lines of a format XXXXXX_N where N is some number. For example:

```
41010401_1
42023920_3
45788_1
```

I would like to add N-1 lines before every line where N>1 such that I have lines for the specified XXXX value with all N values up to and including the original N:

```
41010401_1
42023920_1
42023920_2
42023920_3
45788_1
```

I thought about doing it with sed but I'm not sure how to conditionally append different amount of lines with different value which is based on what sed reads.
Is sed even the correct command to deal with this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted. I think I was clear enough and specific enough to not merit a downvote. oh well.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but questions with no obvious attempt often get numerous downvotes here

Comment: Well, I think I asked a very specific question about the way a very specific command can deal with a very specific scenario, if at all. I could write down some failed attempts but I know these are useless to anybody who can answer this question. I was also quite sure that this question is small enough to not be considered a "do my homework" kind of question. I don't really know what people expect but I guess you can't please everyone.

Comment: Exactly. Don't worry though, I upvoted your question to compensate the downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is to set field separators to underscore and print all missing records when 2nd field is greater than 1 in a loop like below.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} $2>1{for(i=1;i<$2;i++) print $1,i} 1' file
41010401_1
42023920_1
42023920_2
42023920_3
45788_1
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I was used to working with sed. Was starting to look for solutions with other commands and specifically with awk when you posted this solution. Thanks!

Comment: sed is good for trivial replacements, for more complex tasks like yours above, awk is more convenient

Comment: Small follow-up question: I think I understood what each part of the awk statement does, except the 1 in the end. Without it the original line is not printed. Can you please explain why?

Comment: @Ne_Plus_Ultra See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script